# Datareader not reading return value for unique identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

The SQL on this works beautiful when typed into my SQL Client. However, when I try to do this programmatically in csharp no data is returned.  The data is added to the follows_fb_threads table, but the error comes when I try and read from data reader.  it tells me that my data is null.

```
        SqlDataReader dr;

        using (cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO followups_fb_threads (thread_id, thread_time, sender_name, sender_fb_id, sender_location) VALUES (@thread_id, @thread_time, @sender_name, @sender_fb_id, @sender_location); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS [SCOPE_IDENTITY];", con)) ;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("thread_id", thread_id));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("thread_time", thread_time));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("sender_name", sender_name));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("sender_fb_id", master_sender_fb_id));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("sender_location", sender_location));
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        string type_id = dr[0].ToString();  // YOU SHOULD HAVE DATA BUT IS NULL? WTH?
```

Comment: I figured out that I was missing the `dr.Read();` command after the line `dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();`

Answer (score 2):

Shoot. I figured this out. needed. dr.Read();  Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `Read` before there is anything in the data reader:

```
dr.Read();
```

Also, the insert may produce a result, in that case you have to go on to the next result before you can get the identity:

```
dr.NextResult();
dr.Read();
```

Answer (score 2):

you could also do `string type_id = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();` to assign immediately and avoid using the SQLDataReader object.